# How do I reference an object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json

In Javascript, I have an object:

```
obj = { one: "foo", two: "bar" };
```

Now, I want do do this

```
var a = 'two';
if(confirm('Do you want One'))
{
  a = 'one';
}

alert(obj.a);
```

But of course it doesn't work.  What would be the correct way of referencing this object dynamically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

short answer: `obj[a]`

long answer: `obj.field` is just a shorthand for `obj["field"]`, for the special case where the key is a constant string without spaces, dots, or other nasty things.  in your question, the key wasn't a constant, so simply use the full syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
obj[a]
```

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, global variables are attached to the "window" object, so you can do

```
var myGlobal = 'hello';
var a = 'myGlobal';
alert(window[a] + ', ' + window.myGlobal + ', ' + myGlobal);
```

This will alert "hello, hello, hello"