# Using a string to access a variable

Tags: javascript

I currently have a Javascript function that uses a string to reference an object name and acces its properties. I'm currently using eval() to get the the desired effect which I know is very, very wrong. Here is an example of how I'm currently achieving what I want:

```
var stringToObjectRef = function() {

    var myTestVar = "myTestObject";
    var myTestObject = { 'item1' : 100, 'item2' : 12, 'item4' : 18 };

    var myValue = eval(myTestVar + '.item1');

    alert(myValue);

}();
```

I've tried using something like [myTestVar].item1, but this returns undefined. What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're talking about the `item1` part, you're looking for:

```
myValue = myTestObject["item1"];
```

No need for `eval`. (There almost never is.)

If you're talking about getting at the `myTestObject` variable using a "myTestObject" string, you want to refactor the code so you're not doing that, rather than using `eval`. Unfortunately the variable object used for symbol resolution within the function is not accessible directly. The refactor could just use an object explicitly:

```
var stringToObjectRef = function() {

    var objects = {};

    var myTestVar = "myTestObject";
    objects.myTestObject = { 'item1' : 100, 'item2' : 12, 'item4' : 18 };

    var myValue = objects[myTestVar].item1;

    alert(myValue);

}();
```

Off-topic, I don't recall precisely why, but if you're going to execute that anonymous function immediately like that, you need to put the function expression in parentheses:

```
var x = (function() { return 5; })();
```

rather than

```
var x = function() { return 5; }();
```

Again, I don't recall why, and whether it was because of an implementation bug in a popular interpreter or an actual requirement of the syntax.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after, thanks! And thanks for the extra tip as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var stringToObjectRef = function() {
  var myTestObject = { 'item1' : 100, 'item2' : 12, 'item4' : 18 };
  var myValue = myTestObject['item1'];
  alert(myValue);
}();
```

Comment: I'm looking at optimising my code, so I want to remove all the eval() statements in my code. I'm 99.9% certain I don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

eval("myTestObject[\"item1\"") should do the trick, as 
myTestObject.item1 is shorthand for myTestObject["item1"]

[How do I reference an object dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169731/how-do-i-reference-an-object-dynamically/169740#169740)